# HP Envy 6 AMD overheating

Tags: hp, overheating

I installed Ubuntu and everything is fine and working (I think). However, my laptop seems to overheat faster and get hotter than it does when it's running Windows.

How do I find out if all the hardware is installed correctly? And what's causing the heating issue?

I'm not doing anything on the laptop that could cause it to heat up. I have just been installing [Steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_%28software%29), [Spotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) and setting up [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird).

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP Envy 4, and I used to have the same problem. It's happening because both video cards (Intel/ATI) are enabled at the same time (it's what I discovered after research). I tried many ways to install the ATI Radeon driver, but unsuccessfully. So I found a way to use only the active video card (Intel) and disable the ATI card.

After these steps, I felt my Envy was cooler than before. I intent to stay this way until I can find an ATI driver that works!

In the terminal, edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add this line before the line "exit 0":

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Save and reboot.